# Multiple self-deletion of content

Tags: discussion

A few times now, I've been seeing flags of high-reputation users deleting valuable content.

Following the guidance [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action) and [here](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/how-to-deal-with-self-vandalism), I've been rolling back such deletions and, if it comes to it, locking the contested post.

The specific reason I'm doing it is because [all users have](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing):

> You agree that any and all content, including without limitation any and all text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, animations, and product feedback (collectively, "Content") that you provide to the public Network (collectively, "Subscriber Content"), is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Overflow on a worldwide, royalty-free, non-exclusive basis pursuant to Creative Commons licensing terms (CC-BY-SA)

which means:

> This means that you cannot revoke permission for Stack Overflow to publish, distribute, store and use such content and to allow others to have derivative rights to publish, distribute, store and use such content.

Posting just so that it's clear. Feedback appreciated, but I'm not sure what we should be doing differently.

Comment: Where can I upvote a question being closed?  +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is the "valuable" part.

There is a "delete" button, which means the platform offers its users the chance to delete their content. In many cases, they should be able to do so. On the other hand, I agree that when the content has proven especially valuable (for example, if it has many upvotes, or comments, or is the accepted answer), then the community may have the right to preserve it.

Personally, I like to delete my own answers when they receive no upvotes and no comments after a few months. Maybe I misunderstood the question, or I didn't make my point clear enough. I don't want useless answers to stick around, and I like to have the option to remove them.

Comment: I tend to agree. The problem deletions for me are as you say: high voted or accepted answers. Low, no, or negative votes I’m ok with deletion. The latter tidies things up and makes the remainder more relevant.

Comment: @Royi Done!  Feel free to email me at "kootsoop at gmail" rather than post here.

Comment: I will try remembering. Any change you put it on your profile?

Answer (score 0):

This is not good.

People do not put serious material, as of Journal publications, in these open platforms. So claiming a right on them is quite absurd? Claiming a right on my chat-box, comments and homework solutions is quite funny :-)

People should be able to delete their material, as easy as they could add it. This is how a painter, poet, a writer and all copyright holders like working. They ARE to delete whatever they wish. It does not belong to the museum. At least unless sold for money...